# Google App Engine: receive email then/and forward it?

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

I've got an app engine app that receives email and sends its meta-data to a script for processing. It works well. The code is below and was provided from Google via a Github example.

The question is, however, how can I forward email received by this script (or App Engine in general) to another email address?

Specially, with my clients who are using Gmail to forward me their email, I want to receive their forwarding requests so that I, as a human administrator, can approve them.

```
import webapp2
import logging
import urllib
import json

from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch


class HandleEmail(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):

        # parse out fields
        to = message.to
        sender = message.sender
        cc = getattr(message, 'cc', '')
        date = message.date
        subject = message.subject

        # Original message, as a python email.message.Message
        original = str(message.original)

        html_body = ''
        for _, body in message.bodies('text/html'):
            html_body = body.decode()

        plain_body = ''
        for _, plain in message.bodies('text/plain'):
            plain_body = plain.decode()

        # Attachements are EncodedPayload objects, see
        # https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/
        # python/google/appengine/api/mail.py#536
        attachments = [{
                        'filename': attachment[0],
                        'encoding': attachment[1].encoding,
                        'payload': attachment[1].payload
                       }
                       for attachment
                       in getattr(message, 'attachments', [])]

        # logging, remove what you find to be excessive
        logging.info('sender: %s', sender)
        logging.info('to: %s', to)
        logging.info('cc: %s', cc)
        logging.info('date: %s', date)
        logging.info('subject: %s', subject)
        logging.info('html_body: %s', html_body)
        logging.info('plain_body: %s', plain_body)
        logging.info('attachments: %s', [a['filename'] for a in attachments])

        # POST (change to your endpoint, httpbin is cool for testing though)
        # url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
        url = 'https://myapp.appspot.com/receiver.php'

        form_fields = urllib.urlencode({
          'sender': sender.encode('utf8'),
          'to': to.encode('utf8'),
          'cc': cc.encode('utf8'),
          'date': date.encode('utf8'),
          'subject': subject.encode('utf8'),
          'html_body': html_body.encode('utf8'),
          'plain_body': plain_body.encode('utf8'),
          'original': original.encode('utf8'),
          'attachments': json.dumps(attachments)
        })

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
        }

        result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
                                method=urlfetch.POST,
                                payload=form_fields,
                                headers=headers)

        # log more
        logging.info('POST to %s returned: %s', url, result.status_code)
        logging.info('Returned content: %s', result.content)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([HandleEmail.mapping()], debug=True)
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api

Comment: Am I? I guess I am. "Forwarding" is what the end-user refers to it at as. But I guess the back end is receiving the message and then sending it. I don't know much about email so if there is no such thing as "forwarding" at a protocol level, then this is it.

Comment: I believe you've answered your own question then : ) cause only you can "forward/send" an email based on your command

Comment: True that. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, you can use mail.send_mail() function to achieve this in your current class.

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity #[ If you want current user as the sender ]
from google.appengine.api import mail

def forward_mail(sender_address,forward_address,original_message,html_body,original_attachments):
    # [START forward_mail]
    message = mail.EmailMessage(
        subject= original_message.subject,
        to = forward_address,
        sender = original_message.sender,
        body = html_body,
        attachments = original_attachments
    )   

    message.send()
    # [END forward_mail]
```

Then call this function in your HandleEmail class.

Hope it helps

Comment: `EmailMessage()` is being called here with a duplicate named argument `sender` is set to both `sender_address` and `original_message.sender`  -- can anyone say from experience that it's possible to call `EmailMessage()` with `sender = original_message.sender` ?